# opam upgrade to most recent version failure

Tags: ocaml, failed-installation, opam

On an Ubuntu 64-bit version 22.04 device, I have `opam` and `ocaml` installed, with ocaml having version 4.08.0 and I would like to upgrade it to 5.1.0 to use the `Effects` package. However, running `opam install ocaml.5.1.0` the error in the attached photo arises. What can I do to fix this problem?

[installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIAKT.png)

I have tried looking up this issue in other forums, but I couldn't find anything since this version is still quite new.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. It makes your question much less accessible. That said, opam is based on "switches" that are tied to specific version of OCaml (so you're able to switch between them). In order to upgrade OCaml you need to create a new switch for the version you want.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I have a better understanding of how OCaml works. I have created a new switch and the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Introduction to opam switches](https://ocaml.org/docs/opam-switch-introduction)

In short, you need to create a new opam switch for OCaml 5.1.0 and then *switch* to it.

```
opam update

opam create switch 5.1.0

opam switch 5.1.0
```